# How do I create a vector using the data from the vector

Tags: c++, vector

I manage to insert values into range vector, but in range vector I have data RangeA, RangeB, RangeC..

Using this data, I want to create a vector for this range under block vector, how am I supposed to go with it?

```
vector <string> range;
for(int i=0;i<range.size();i++)
{
    cout<<"range: "<<range[i]<<endl;
    vector <string> block[i];                  <<<<<<<
}
```

Output:

range: RangeA

range: RangeB

range: RangeC

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to copy or what exactly?

Comment: `vector<string> block(i); `

Comment: having those output, i want to create a vector for each

Comment: Are you copying a vector or copying separate items to another vector?

Comment: On what criterion, Ranges needs to be spitted from `range` vector ?

Comment: @user1745860 having (i) you want to create what vector? vector of size (i)?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <string> range;
for(int i=0;i<range.size();i++)
{
    cout<<"range: "<<range[i]<<endl;

    // create a vector of size i
    // with each element of default 
    // value "default"
    vector <string> block(i,string("default")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> range;
//Create block vector with size
//same as range vector
vector <string> block(range.size());
//Now you can iterate range vector 
//and initialize the block vector with value 
for (int i = 0 ; i < range.size(); i++)
{
    block[i]=string(range[i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < block.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<block[i];
}
```